# Issue using pip download -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, libraries, python-wheel

I have my Python script and my requirements.txt ready.

What I want to do is to get all the packages listed in the "requirements.txt" into a folder. In the bundle, I'd for example have the full packages of "pymysql", "bs4" as well as all their dependencies.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Could you help me please? I am stuck and I am really struggling with this.

I am using Python 3.6

I am using "pip download -r requirements.txt" but it's not downloading the dependencies and outputs me only.whl files whereas I'm looking for "proper" folders..

Answer (score 6):

To make pip prefer source files over wheels, use the `--no-binary` flag:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt --no-binary :all: -d /path/to/download/dir
```

Comment: this is installing the libraries locally. This is not what i'm looking for. I want to have these packages as folders